# VisualD/Visual Studio Cannot Open Premake Generated .visualdproj

Tags: visual-studio, d, premake, visual-d

I've been trying out premake with D, and have found that Visual Studio cannot open the generated `visualdproj` files. Even the example given in the [readme](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/tree/master/modules/d) for the module does not work. However, a C project appears to work just fine even in the same solution. What is happening here?

This is my `premake5.lua`:

```
workspace "Test"
    configurations { "release", "debug" }

    project "app"
        language "D"
        kind "ConsoleApp"
        files "source/app.d"

    project "app2"
        language "C"
        kind "ConsoleApp"
        files "source2/app.c"
```

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you use?

Comment: VS Community 2019